# Acces to import of the nested function JS

Tags: javascript, function, export, nested-function

I need some help to get how some function export works inside JS.
Let's say I have this code

```
function goodbuy() {
    console.log('bye');
}
function myModule() {
    function hello() {
        console.log('Hello');
    }
    hello();
}

export {goodbuy};
export default myModule;
```

If I call it:

```
import {goodbuy} from "./main";
import hello from "./main";

goodbuy();
hello();
```

The output is:

**bye
Hello**

But if I remove `hello()` call from `function myModule()`  it does not work.

```
function myModule() {
    function hello() {
        console.log('Hello');
    }
}
```

with output:

**bye**

It is a little bit strange for me, as I did not import myModule() where this hello() is called.

PyCharm and VS Code does not show function hello() is not reachable, seems I can export it, but can't use without calling inside the main  function myModule().

Could somebody please explain how it works?

I would like an explanation why this function can work with calling inside the main function and can't work without it.

Comment: _"I did not import myModule() where this hello() called"_ - yes you did, what you call `hello` in `import hello from "./main"` **is** `myModule`, that's the default export.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

** return hellow() from myModule**
** And called hellow function like myModule()()**

```
function goodbuy() {
console.log("bye");
}
function myModule() {
return function hello() {
  console.log("Hello");
};
}

export { goodbuy };
export default myModule;

  enter code here
import myModule from "./main";
import {goodbuy} from "./main";

goodbuy();
myModule()();
```

Comment: function myModule() {
  return function hello() {
    console.log("Hello");
  };
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
import hello from "./main";
```

You are importing the `default export` from the other file, which is `myModule`, due to this line:

```
export default myModule;
```

You could actually replace that `import` with any other name:

```
import foo from "./main";
import something from "./main";
...
```

They are all importing the `default export` from that file.

This is not the same as importing the `hello` function defined inside the `myModule` function. If you want that, you should probably use [named exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#description) and write something like this:

```
function goodbuy() {
    console.log('bye');
}

function hello() {
    console.log('Hello');
}

export { hello, goodbuy };
```

The only reason you see `Hello` in the first case is becase:

- You import `myModule` (now aliases as `hello`).
- You call `myModule` (as `hello()`).
- `myModule` internally calls the `hello` `function` defined within itself.